# I am not able to add reference of my class into my aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a folder named "_CLASS"

in this folder i am having on class named "SqlAccess" which is having some methods.

now i want to use this class in my .aspx.cs page, so i have to add reference name space for the "SqlAccess" class, which is "SQL" (namespace)

but it give me error like

```
"The type or namespace name 'SQL' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

**EDIT**

This is my class which is under "_CLASS" folder

```
namespace SQl
{

   public class SqlAccess
   {
      //...... here is my code 
   }
}
```

Or i need to add this class under "App_Code" folder ? if yes then why?

Comment: Check for namespace errors. What is the access modifier of the class?

Comment: Access modifier is "public"

Comment: It's looking for "SQL" but your namespace is "SQl"...

Comment: its only because of font....

Comment: It should be in App_Code folder.

Comment: is it compulsory to add class in App_Code???

Answer (score 1):

> Or i need to add this class under "App_Code" folder ?

If you are using a WebSite then you should use the App_Code folder to add code.

If you are using a WebApplication, then you can place the code wherever you want.

Please refer to the [`WebSite vs Web Application article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) on MSDN.

Also from the error message you seem to have used `SQL` as namespace but in the code you have shown you used `SQl` which obviously is not the same thing in C#.

Comment: +1 for linked explanation and character casing pick up like me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Right Click the class >> Properties and check the **Build Action**. It should be **Compile**.